# How are set items generated?

Tags: torchlight-2

I got two different helmets and both seem to be for the same set.

[image]

So how exactly does the generation of set items works? Do ALL items you obtain have a chance to be a part of a set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General Grell's Doomhelm counts as a piece of the Runemaster set for purposes of calculating set bonuses. Of the sets [currently documented](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Sets_%28T2%29) on Torchlight Wiki, this is the only set with such a feature, though further gameplay may reveal otherwise.